# Return type from generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I'm Sorry again but this question continuance of my first question:
consider this Interface:

```
 interface IRepository<T,U> where T:class where U:class 
{
    IEnumerable<U> SelectAll();

    bool Insert(T item);

    IEnumerable<T> FindAll(Func<T, bool> exp);
}
```

and I Implement this interface:

```
 public class Repository : IRepository<Customer,Select4ColumnsOfCustomers>
{

    #region IRepository<Customer,Select4ColumnsOfCustomers> Members

    public IEnumerable<Select4ColumnsOfCustomers> SelectAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Insert(Customer item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> FindAll(Func<Customer, bool> exp)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

public class Select4ColumnsOfCustomers
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I want to return just 4 column of Customer table in northwind database.
Ok.this work but if I want to add other method that return other types I must declare S,U,M,W,... in Interface and in Implement of it I must write this Code:

```
public class Repository : IRepository<Customer,RetType1,RetType2,RetType3,....>
```

this not good.what is alternative for this.Is it possible that write var for Return Types?Or a place holder for return types?
thanks

Comment: Consider using `Datatable` or an ORM for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Your repository can implement multiple interfaces.

```
public class Repository : IRepository<TResult1, T1>, IRepository<Tresult2, T2>, etc...
```

Your SelectAll method will need to be generic like

```
TResult SelectAll<TResult>();
```

However Andrzej is right, consider using an ORM so that you can generalize this code. Check out [NHiberante](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @Nima, sorry I actually don't have much experience with EF. In NHibernate, what I've typically done is create repository class that deals with CRUD operations and the a set of Query classes for specific querying.